# inconsistent distinct + order by behavior between mysql 5.6 and 5.7

Tags: mysql, order-by, distinct

I use MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 on `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS` and I have a problem with the following query (which is derived from drupal 7 but have simplified it in order to pinpoint the issue):

```
select distinct node.nid, node.title, users.name
  from node
  left join users on node.uid = users.uid
  order by node.nid desc
  limit 4;
```

My servers are provisioned with the exact same ansible script which uses the following `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
key_buffer_size         = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 1G
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
query_cache_type        = 0
slow_launch_time=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
innodb_file_per_table
open-files-limit=10000
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
long_query_time=2
slow_query_log=on
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow-queries.log
general_log=off
general_log_file=/var/log/mysql/general.log
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
```

I import my database and then connect to CLI using:

```
echo "create database drupal" | mysql -u root -ppass
mysql -u root -ppass drupal < /vagrant/2017-10-13--08-00-backup-xxxx-db.sql
mysql -u root -ppass drupal -A
```

On servers with 5.6 (`show variables like 'version';` gives me `5.6.16-1~exp1`) the query returns the following rows which are in the correct descending order (note: used some `x` characters to anonymize dataset):

```
+-------+------------------------------------------+------+
| nid   | title                                    | name |
+-------+------------------------------------------+------+
| 56217 | A Coxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   | ztex |
| 56216 | Estxxxxxxxxx                             | ctex |
| 56215 | Plexxxxxxxxxxxxxx                        | xovr |
| 56214 | Cloxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx | xovr |
+-------+------------------------------------------+------+
```

But in servers with 5.7 (`show variables like 'version';` gives me `5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log`) I get the opposite `nid` order from what I expect:

```
+-----+---------------------------+------+
| nid | title                     | name |
+-----+---------------------------+------+
|   1 | AEGQ todo - January 2009  | xc   |
|   2 | AEGQ todo - February 2009 | xc   |
|   3 | AEGQ todo - March 2009    | xc   |
|   4 | AEGQ todo - May 2009      | xc   |
+-----+---------------------------+------+
```

In both cases the `explain extended` and `show warnings` outputs look the same.

5.6:

```
mysql> explain extended select distinct node.nid, node.title, users.name from node left join users on node.uid = users.uid order by node.nid desc limit 4;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+------+------------+-----------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref             | rows | filtered   | Extra           |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+------+------------+-----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | node  | index  | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL            |    4 | 1359550.00 | Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | drupal.node.uid |    1 |     100.00 | Using where     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+------+------------+-----------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Level: Note
   Code: 1003
Message: /* select#1 */ select distinct `drupal`.`node`.`nid` AS `nid`,`drupal`.`node`.`title` AS `title`,`drupal`.`users`.`name` AS `name` from `drupal`.`node` left join `drupal`.`users` on((`drupal`.`node`.`uid` = `drupal`.`users`.`uid`)) where 1 order by `drupal`.`node`.`nid` desc limit 4
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

5.7:

```
mysql> explain extended select distinct node.nid, node.title, users.name from node left join users on node.uid = users.uid order by node.nid desc limit 4;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+------+----------+-----------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref             | rows | filtered | Extra           |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+------+----------+-----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | node  | NULL       | index  | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL            |    4 |   100.00 | Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | drupal.node.uid |    1 |   100.00 | Using where     |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+------+----------+-----------------+
2 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1681
Message: 'EXTENDED' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
*************************** 2. row ***************************
  Level: Note
   Code: 1003
Message: /* select#1 */ select distinct `drupal`.`node`.`nid` AS `nid`,`drupal`.`node`.`title` AS `title`,`drupal`.`users`.`name` AS `name` from `drupal`.`node` left join `drupal`.`users` on((`drupal`.`node`.`uid` = `drupal`.`users`.`uid`)) where 1 order by `drupal`.`node`.`nid` desc limit 4
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

On both servers `show variables like 'coll%';` returns the same:

```
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
```

And of course, on both servers the schema and data are the same:

```
| node  | CREATE TABLE `node` (
  `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `language` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `changed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `promote` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sticky` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tnid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `translate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rh_action` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rh_redirect` longtext,
  `rh_redirect_response` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`nid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `vid` (`vid`),
  KEY `node_changed` (`changed`),
  KEY `node_created` (`created`),
  KEY `node_frontpage` (`promote`,`status`,`sticky`,`created`),
  KEY `node_status_type` (`status`,`type`,`nid`),
  KEY `node_title_type` (`title`,`type`(4)),
  KEY `node_type` (`type`(4)),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `tnid` (`tnid`),
  KEY `translate` (`translate`),
  KEY `language` (`language`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=56997 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='The base table for nodes.' |
```

and

```
| users | CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pass` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `mail` varchar(254) DEFAULT '',
  `theme` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `signature` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `signature_format` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `access` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `login` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timezone` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `picture` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `init` varchar(254) DEFAULT '',
  `data` longblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `access` (`access`),
  KEY `created` (`created`),
  KEY `mail` (`mail`),
  KEY `picture` (`picture`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Stores user data.' |
```

To recap, what is the same:

- O/S, kernel, software components and underlying virtualization method
- `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
- imported database file (schema + data are the same)
- database user
- select query
- explain select output
- server, database and connection collations

What is different:

- mysql version
- `sql_mode`. As shown in my `my.cnf` I've left defaults for 5.6 and 5.7 which are:
- - 5.6: `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`
- - 5.7: `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Problem:

- order of results looks wrong on mysql 5.7

How can this be explained? Have the semantics of distinct keyword changed in MySQL 5.7?

Comment: [Comments archived](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89582/discussion-on-question-by-cherouvim-inconsistent-distinct-order-by-behavior-be).

Answer (score 3):

We don't get to say this often but in this case:

**If this happens, it's a bug.**

A query that has:

```
SELECT
  .. DISTINCT 
  ..
ORDER BY node.nid DESC
LIMIT 4 ;
```

should apply the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` after the `SELECT` - whether it's a `SELECT DISTINCT` or not - and return the rows with the highest four `nid` values in descending order. In the 5.7.20 case, it seems that it doesn't and the `ORDER BY` is ignored (or it runs as `ASC`), and the rows are returned with ascending order, so it must be a bug.

The right thing to do in these cases, is to report the bug with a sample test case, to MySQL bug list.

Things you could also do - to confirm, make it easier for MySQL developers to fix, and remedy the issue until the bug is fixed - is to try:

- remove the `DISTINCT`, seems useless anyway. The `node.nid` is unique since it's the primary key and the join is on `user.uid` which is the primary key of the other table, so the distinct will have no effect.
- remove the `DISTINCT` and add `GROUP BY node.nid, node.title, users.name` or just `GROUP BY node.nid, users.name`.
- remove the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` setting.
- try the query in older minor versions (5.7.19, 5.7.18, ...)

And please include the findings (if the bug persists with the above tries) in your bug report to MySQL - to help them identify the cause of the problem. I suspect it's a regression due to some optimization improvement related to `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Submitted bug with steps to reproduce and a very minimal database dump which consistently reproduces the problem: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=88814